# Cannot connect to Private, Regional GKE endpoint from OpenVPN client

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, openvpn, private-subnet, terraform-provider-gcp

I created the GKE [Private Cluster](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/03/kubernetes-engine-private-clusters-now.html) via Terraform ([google_container_cluster](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html) with `private = true` and `region` set) and installed the `stable/openvpn` Helm Chart. My setup is basically the same as described in this article: https://itnext.io/use-helm-to-deploy-openvpn-in-kubernetes-to-access-pods-and-services-217dec344f13 and I am able to see a `ClusterIP`-only exposed service as described in the article. However, while I am connected to the VPN, `kubectl` fails due to not being able to reach the master.

I left the [`OVPN_NETWORK` setting](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/openvpn/values.yaml#L57) as the default (`10.240.0.0`), and changed the `OVPN_K8S_POD_NETWORK` and subnet mask setting to the secondary range I chose when I created my private subnet that the Private Cluster lives in.

I even tried adding `10.240.0.0/16` to my [`master_authorized_networks_config`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#master_authorized_networks_config) but I'm pretty sure that setting only works on external networks (adding the external IP of a completely different OVPN server allows me to run `kubectl` when I'm connected to it).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: I just remembered I had to set a value for [`master_ipv4_cidr_block`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#master_ipv4_cidr_block) in order to create a Private Cluster. So I added `10.0.0.0/28` to the [ovpn.conf file](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/openvpn/values.yaml) as `push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.240"` but that didn't help. The docs on this setting states:

> Specifies a private RFC1918 block for the master's VPC. The master
>   range must not overlap with any subnet in your cluster's VPC. The
>   master and your cluster use VPC peering. Must be specified in CIDR
>   notation and must be /28 subnet.

but what's the implication for an OpenVPN client on a subnet outside of the cluster? How do I leverage the aforementioned VPC peering?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out what the problem is: `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` always writes the master's external IP address to `~/.kube/config`. So `kubectl` always talks to that external IP address instead of the internal IP.

To fix: I ran `kubectl get endpoints`, noted the `10.0.0.x` IP and replaced the external IP in `~/.kube/config` with it. Now `kubectl` works fine while connected to the OVPN server inside of the Kube cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `--internal-ip` to your gcloud command to put automatically the internal ip address to `~/.kube/config` file